# Use light cone/range as a Trigger

Tags: c#, unity, lighting

I was wondering, in Unity 3D, how I could do something with the Spot Light (Range/cone) as a trigger? Since it would be very interesting to be able to manipulate whats actually in sight of Light range/cone, and then trigger an event / method.

Example of the Spot Light (Range/cone)

[image: Spot Light Range Cone]

Since i'm at a Game Jam right now, I don't have infinite time, so some help or atlest thoughts on this, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is it going to be 2D? if so you could simple check if an object is within the light cone by comparing the angle.

Comment: No it's gonna be 3D, so I need full flexiblity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but in Unity the surefire approach to anything tends to follow this pattern:

1. Create an empty GameObject.
2. Create a cone shaped collider and set as a trigger, e.g. using something like this: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CreateCone
3. Move the spotlight and collider under the GameObject.
4. Put a script on the GameObject which allows changing the range etc, possibly by scaling the collider or possibly by re-generating the mesh.
5. Moving/rotating should work fine because you always move/rotate the parent GameObject.

Comment: I see.. That was just what I needed. An insight into how to make such thing. I appreciate it mate.

Comment: No problems. Sometimes the Unity mindset takes a while to get.